# Omit Aggregate Column in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to omit an aggregate column in a query?  As an example:

```
SELECT Id, Description, MAX(Created)
FROM Record
GROUP BY Id, Description
```

How do I omit the MAX(Created) column from my result set?  **This query is being used in a sub-query** so I can join to the most recent record and omit any older records.  I know it won't make a large difference, but in general my practice has been to only bring back data you need, and in this case I just want to join to the most recent record, and pull out the description.  I don't actually care what the date is.

Any thoughts?  Am I being too picky?

Comment: Why not just rewrite the query and remove the aggregate function? Query strings are free and you won't have to pay extra for having a regular and an aggregate-enabled version of the query.

Comment: Provide the entire query for this to make sense, please.

Comment: Why do you have an aggregate in the select clause if you don't need it?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server, and is this subquery correlated to any outer query?

Comment: @marapet - It's a sub-query.  If this wasn't being used as a sub-query, I'd just remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the Description (1 record) of the most recent record (MAX(Created)), then

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, Description
FROM Record
ORDER BY CREATED DESC
```

Comment: Interesting, this is a good idea.  Have any performance thoughts on using the TOP 1 / ORDER BY versus doing the MAX function?

Comment: @Ek0nomik - TOP(1) is at least as fast as MAX. But don't even worry about performance, worry about the fact that MAX(x) doesn't give you the correlated Description of the same record whereas Top(1) does.

Answer (score 1):

```
select TOP 1 ID, Description from Record
    group by ID, Description order by MAX(Created) DESC
```

You cannot use an aggregate function without grouping columns.

And like mentioned above you may not even need an aggregate function

```
select TOP 1 ID, Description from Record order by Created DESC
```

Comment: You caught me in the middle of editing my post to add the grouping.  :)

Comment: SQL allows you to use an aggregate function without grouping columns. But Ek0nomik can't do that, because the subquery wouldn't return the same rows. (Not arguing with you. Just being more explicit.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, can't you just remove the column you don't want from the select?

```
SELECT Id, Description
FROM Record
ORDER BY Created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The query I listed above is a sub-query, so if I remove the MAX(Created), then I am no longer retrieving just the most recent records to join onto.

Comment: Just add an ORDER BY col LIMIT 1 to your subquery.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Description
FROM Record
```